# Make a folder in SVN writable so that when the repo is checked out, the permissions are already set to writable?

Tags: svn, permissions, file-permissions, directory

I'm not a Subversion pro by any means.  But I am using it for my coding projects and using the deployment feature at springloops.com (love it).

I have some log, cache and image folders that I routinely need to make writable on new deployments or new projects.  Is there a way to make it so that when deploying or downloading, the folder permissions will already be set to `0777`?

Comment: I must be missing something - when I check out a working folder with Subversion, everything is writable by default. As I understand it, this is how svn works out of the box.

Comment: Sorry, to be a little clearer: Writable by the scripting language the project uses. ie: so the PHP script can write to certain folders in using the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Subversion doesn't support storing permissions. According to this discussion ([Nabble "Unix file permissions" (external link)](http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/Unix-file-permissions-td91069.html)), however, one can use svn properties and a little bit of shell scripting.

To store the properties in subversion:

```
$ svn propset owner username aFile 
$ svn propset group groupname aFile 
$ svn propset mode filemode aFile
```

To later re-apply the file permissions:

```
$ chown `svn propget owner aFile`.`svn propget group aFile` aFile
$ chmod `svn propget mode aFile` aFile
```

Answer (score 2):

svn can't store file (or folder) permissions, so I'm afraid your only option is to write a script to make the task a little less tedious.

Answer (score 0):

When you check out a working copy, by definition you have write access to the whole working copy.

Comment: That's not the same as `0777`, and it doesn't mean that the webserver user will have write access.